# Why is Firefox claiming a reset connection

Tags: firefox, iframe, ssl, https, cgi

I'm working on a password maker page at http://JonathansCorner.com/passwords/. Because that page is not encrypted (and the site does not have an SSL certificate), I have a skeleton page that loads https://haywardfamily.org/password.cgi in an iframe.

Works great on every browser I've tested except Firefox--even IE6! In Firefox it usually says that the connection was reset:

*The connection was reset*

*The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.*

*The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.*

This happens most of the time; occasionally Firefox loads it. If I load the iframe contents, Firefox handles it without a hitch.

What is going on, and is there any way I can implement things so Firefox will load the iframe correctly?

Comment: You do realize that framing an https page in an http page is insecure, right?  In particular someone can MITM the outer page and stick whatever page they want in the subframe....